# Firefox address bar lost browsing history

Tags: firefox

When I type "apo" my firefox address bar used to suggest autocompletions, the top of which was always my blog "apokatastasicosmosis.com". For some weird reason it has stopped doing this and now all I get are search suggestions.

How do I turn it back on?

Comment: Consider not advertising your content on the question when it's totally unrelated to what you ask (but put it in your profile if you wish!) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to preferences and select Privacy & Security option in the menu. Scroll down and you will find

#### Address Bar

Check the Browsing history option.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `about:preferences#privacy` (just paste this in the address bar).

In the `Address Bar` section, under `When using the address bar, suggest`, check that the `Browsing history` checkbox is checked.